# Common LISP passing fewer arguments than required - what is going on?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I am currently studying some code (not mine) which involves polynomials in order to better understand Functional Style LISP Programming.

```
(define collect-terms(a)
  (sort a #'compare))

(defun compare(a b)
  (llt (car (cdr a)) (car (cdr b))))
```

I don't understand how the compare method can take just one argument when it is called in collect-terms when the function definition states two.

In this case, compare successfully takes out sublists of the list it is passed and uses them as values for a and b.

Comment: Common Lisp has no `define`.

Answer (score 6):

`collect-terms` is not calling `compare` at all.  It is passing `compare` to the `sort` function, which will call `compare` with two arguments.

Comment: But compare still requires two arguments, no?

How is it taking these even though it only has one list to work with?

Or am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: `sort` calls whatever comparison function you give it on elements taken from the list you give it, two at a time.